# Initialize an array with a variable contening key

Tags: bash

I want to construct an arry with the result of a SQLite query.
I do

```
result=`sqlite3 "$database" 'SELECT id,value FROM table'`
```

I obtain

> 1|value for id 1
>
> 2|value for id 2

(By defaut, sqlite use | as separator).
What I want is using the *id* as the key in the bash array, and *value* as the bash value.

If I type directly

```
array=([1]="value for id 1" [2]="value for id 2")
```

It work great !
So I modify result this way :

```
result=`sqlite3 "$database" 'SELECT id,value FROM table' | sed 's/^/[' | sed 's/|/]="/' | sed 's/$/"/' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'`
```

and when i do echo "$result", I succesfully obtain :

> [1]="value for id 1" [2]="value for id 2"

But now, when I do

```
array=($result)
array=("$result")
array=($(echo -n $result))
array=($(echo -n "$result"))
array=(`echo -n $result`)
array=(`echo -n "$result"`)
```

None of them work.
If I do

```
for i in "${!array[@]}";do
  echo "key = $i"
  echo "val = ${array[$i]}"
done
```

I end up with something like

> key = 0
>
> val = [1]="value
>
> key = 1
>
> val = for
>
> key = 2
>
> val = id
>
> key = 3
>
> val = 1"
>
> key = 4
>
> val = [2]="value
>
> key = 5
>
> val = for
>
> key = 6
>
> val = id
>
> key = 7
>
> val = 2"

What's wrong ? How can I initalize an array with $result ?

Comment: As an aside, an easier way to print an array's exact contents is `declare -p array`.

Comment: I'm a beginer in bash, I will keep that in mind, thank.
And yes, now you mention it, it's obvious that string can't be interpreted as code. I must be really tired, or dumb, or both ...

Comment: It takes a bit to learn the evaluation model. For some somewhat related discussion, btw, see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process substitution results aren't `eval`uated as code. This is, in short, a Very Good Thing -- if you had a value containing `$(rm -rf $HOME)`, you wouldn't want it to be any other way.

Instead, explicitly read your results and assign them to your array:

```
declare -a array=( )
while IFS='|' read -r key value; do
  array[$key]=$value
done < <(sqlite3 "$database" 'SELECT id,value FROM table')
```